# Show $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\frac{dx}{(1+|x|^2)^{\frac{r}{2}}}<\infty \Leftrightarrow r>n$

Tags: integration

As the title says, I wanted to show　$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\frac{dx}{(1+|x|^2)^{\frac{r}{2}}}<\infty \Leftrightarrow r>n$

I want to take advantage of the fact that when $|x|$ is big enough,  $1+|x|^2$ and $|x|^2$ are about the same, but I can't do it right, so I would be glad to get some advice.

If $n=1$, this can be easily proved, but if $n\geq 2$ (so when this is a multiple integral),　trying to do the same as when n=1 is not possible

Comment: if $n>1$, you can use polar coordinates: $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(|x |) \,dx = c(n)\int_0^\infty r^{n-1}f(r) \, dr$ where $c(n)$ is a constant depending on $n$ only.

Comment: oh!yes! I had forgotten all about that! Thank you!